# Laravel form request duplicate query

Tags: laravel

I want to fetch a record and perform validation with that.

So I see two option using validation in the controller and using form request

I prefer using form request

So according to a document I can fetch a record in Form request and use it.

But the problem is I need that record in the controller too, So if I going this way I load one record twice.

I'm solving my problem with property in the form request

for example

```
/**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $this->post = Post::find($this->input('id'));
        return [
            ... // my rules base on $this->post
        ];
    }
```

and then in the controller, I can access the post value

```
public function store(PostPublishCreate $request)
{
    $request->post;
    ....
```

1.But I'm confused in this way, Is there a problem in my way? Is there a better solution to do it in laravel?

2.In this example I don't use dependency injection, So how I can approach this **with dependency injection**?

```
public function store(PostPublishCreate $request,Post $post)
    {
        // how to prevent to my record provided twice
        // PostPublishCreate load post because of the rules
        // Post loaded again with DI
        ....
```

3. I try to use the `Rule` class for my custom validation, But I'm not sure how to pass the record to `Rule` without reloading it

Answer (score -1):

Form Request is not loading the record. It just validates the parameters present in the $request object. In the second example, $post is automatically retrieved by DI where then you can manipulate your record as you wish.

Comment: The only scenario where you might query the database twice is when using validation rules like `unique`. But this isn't an issue in my opinion, as request validation and business logic should be handled separately anyway.

Comment: I know that, But how I validate record and and also use DI without running a query twice? this is my question, Not where to put my code

Comment: Also note, Validation is the place to write my rules. I want to have it in form request not in controller

Comment: As I said, Form Request is not running a query on your model. It only checks whether the request parameters pass specified validation rules.

Comment: Ok and my validation rule is to check user input based on my record, And because of that I need to run it from database